# how to get complete place address using latitude and longitude on emulator in android?

Tags: android, location, latitude-longitude, google-latitude

This is my code 
It don't have any error but

It shows in textView "No Address returned!"

```
double lat = 18.520430300000000000, log = 73.856743699999920000;
    String address = null;                                                 
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, log, 1); 
        sb = new StringBuilder(); 
        if (addresses.size() > 0) { 

           Address address = addresses.get(0); 

           for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) 
              sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)+ ",");
           txtAdd.setText("Address :"+sb);
        }
        else{
            txtAdd.setText("No Address returned!");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        /*e.printStackTrace();*/
        txtAdd.setText("Canont get Address!");
    }
```

Plz give me solution on this

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

The doku gives one hint, maybe this should help

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

> Returns an array of Addresses that are known to describe the area
>   immediately surrounding the given latitude and longitude. The returned
>   addresses will be localized for the locale provided to this class's
>   constructor.
>
> The returned values may be obtained by means of a network lookup. The
>   results are a best guess and are not guaranteed to be meaningful or
>   correct. **It may be useful to call this method from a thread separate
>   from your primary UI thread.**